# Slicing vector of matrices

Tags: matrix, vector, julia, slice

I would like to slice a vector of matrices by some condition. The code I have now looks like

```
sliced = data[:][[data[:][end,1] .> 0]
```

where `data` is a vector of irregularly sized matrices of size `(n,2)`. The above code doesn't work, because it thinks I'm trying to slice the last element of the vector or something. The overall question I'm trying to ask is whether there is a way to slice an irregular vector of matrices based on some consistent condition?

Comment: In case the meaning was getting items with positive bottom left, then: `[d for d in data if d[end,1]>0]` is nice. But you really should have left a mini example

Comment: The expression `data[:]` does nothing useful in the OP, it just creates a copy of `data` itself. So `data[:][end,1]` is the same as `data[end,1]` except for the extra copy.

Comment: @DanGetz This is the solution I was looking for. If you make it an answer I'll mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe SundarR would like to add to his already comprehensive answer a paragraph about this and you can mark his right (a shame if fewer would read it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Edited based on the clarification of the condition, thanks to @DanGetz*)

Given a `data` vector of matrices:

```
julia> data = [[1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8], [-1 -2], [10 20; 30 40], [9 8; -7 6]]
4-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
 [-1 -2]
 [10 20; 30 40]
 [9 8; -7 6]
```

If we wanted to use logical indexing like in the question, we could broadcasting on an anonymous function like so:

```
julia> data[(m -> m[end, begin] > 0).(data)]
2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
 [10 20; 30 40]
```

But in this case, an array comprehension or a `filter` would be clearer:

```
julia> [m for m in data if m[end, begin] > 0]
2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
 [10 20; 30 40]

julia> filter(data) do (m)
         m[end, begin] > 0
       end
2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
 [10 20; 30 40]
```

(`begin` here is a generic way of writing the first index of an array dimension - it works both for normal arrays where the first index is `1`, and for things like [OffsetArrays](https://juliaarrays.github.io/OffsetArrays.jl/stable/).)

Comment: This is almost what I wanted. The condition I had was a condition that the first element of the final row of my matrices must be greater than 0 `[end,1]`. That's why there is the issue of slicing every matrix by the same slice. Basically I wanted to slice every matrix with `[end,1]`, and find all the matrices which have this value over 0.

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know in case you have further questions on it.